# Getting Search Widget response's lat long in ArcGIS API for Javascript 4.x?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How would I retrieve the lat/long of the city/location selected using the Search Widget?  I do not need to display this location on a map.  All examples I have so far come across attach the Widget to a SceneView or Mapview.

Answer (score 3):

You have to hook the [select-result Event](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#event:select-result) that fires when a search result is selected.

```
var searchWidget = new Search();

searchWidget.on("select-result", function(event){
   // Do whatever you want with your result
   var graphic = event.result.feature
   var extent = event.result.extent

});
```